# Tug could be milk and vodka?

Tags: character, brick

In [Brick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28film%29), when Brendan lays out several words Emily said that he didn't understand, Brain guesses that Tug might be a drink made of a mixture of milk and vodka, but Tug is actually the name of a character. Is there any symbolism to this? Can it be a commentary on Tug's duality of violence and immaturity? Am I just reading too much into it?

Comment: I personally think that u are right, its a commentary on Tug's duality of violence and immaturity... Yes i agree, hope i helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, the writer has a website, and a forum which he posts on...

> Oh man, if Lebowski had been made when I wrote the script I would take credit for this in a HEARTBEAT. Unfortunately it wasn't. I think it's more a comment on now the Brain obviously has never had a drink in his life.

[Rian Johnson's forum post](http://www.rcjohnso.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=338)

Looking through the forum this is the only time he directly makes a comment about this line. And people who I imagine frequented the forums long ago also mention this is the only time he really gives any sort of explanation.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I've been to his site before to answer a question about the Cadillac line in Brothers Bloom. I didn't think to check for this one, so thanks!